# Can I remove or hide or or rename a flutter Package from Pub.dev?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages, flutter-pub

I am new at flutter, I published a package on pub.dev but due to some issues, I have to remove or rename it from there (https://pub.dev/). I want that no one can see it by searching it.
I 'Discontinued' it from pub.dev, but it is still visible from advance search?
Is there any way to hide it permanentally or remove it?

Comment: See https://pub.dev/policy.

Comment: Thanks, i already mailed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although packages always remain published, it can be useful to signal to developers that a package is no longer being actively maintained. For this, you can mark a package as discontinued. So as you did, a discontinued package remains published and viewable on pub.dev, but it has a clear DISCONTINUED badge and doesn’t appear in pub.dev search results.

That is all you can do as far as I know!

Comment: Yes, I did it, And I concluded that I am unable to remove it, I had sent an email to pub.dev team to remove it.

Comment: Did it work then ? Sending an email to pub.dev team ?